# Getting service account credentials Apps Script - TypeError: Cannot read property from null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, looker-studio, service-accounts

I am developing a community connector for Data Studio, directly linked to BigQuery, using Data Studio Advanced Services. However, I am not able to retrieve the service account credentials.

I have already copied and pasted the whole json file for the service account key as a string in `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS` var, as well as the whole string in the 'private_key' in the json in the `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY` var, as well as the service account e-mail and billing project id as strings, respectively in the vars `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` and `BILLING_PROJECT_ID`. It fails when I try to authenticate when I run the `getData()` function.

Code (is the World Bank advanced services example, but with my credentials):

```js
var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function isAdminUser() {
  return false;
}

function getAuthType() {
  return cc
    .newAuthTypeResponse()
    .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.NONE)
    .build();
}

function getConfig(request) {
  var config = cc.getConfig();

  config
    .newInfo()
    .setId('info')
    .setText(
      'No configuration is required for this connector. Click connect to create a new data source.'
    );

  return config.build();
}

function getFields() {
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
  var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;

  fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('country_name')
    .setName('Country')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

  fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('country_code')
    .setName('Country Code')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

  fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('indicator_name')
    .setName('Indicator')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

  fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('year')
    .setName('Year')
    .setType(types.YEAR);

  fields
    .newMetric()
    .setId('value')
    .setName('Value')
    .setType(types.NUMBER)
    .setIsReaggregatable(true)
    .setAggregation(aggregations.SUM);

  return fields;
}

function getSchema(request) {
  return {
    schema: getFields().build()
  };
}

var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS = '{'+
  '"type": "service_account",'+
  '"project_id": "string for the project id",'+
  '"private_key_id": "string for the private key id",'+
  '"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----the private key-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",'+
  '"client_email": "serviceaccount@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",'+
  '"client_id": "the client id",'+
  '"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",'+
  '"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",'+
  '"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",'+
  '"client_x509_cert_url": "url"'+
'}';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'private key string';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'serviceaccount@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
var BILLING_PROJECT_ID = 'projectid';

/**
 * Copy the entire credentials JSON file from creating a service account in GCP.
 */
function getServiceAccountCreds() {
  return JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS));
}

function getOauthService() {
  var serviceAccountCreds = getServiceAccountCreds();
  var serviceAccountKey = serviceAccountCreds[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY];
  var serviceAccountEmail = serviceAccountCreds[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL];

  return OAuth2.createService('WorldBankHealthPopulation')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setPrivateKey(serviceAccountKey)
    .setIssuer(serviceAccountEmail)
    .setPropertyStore(scriptProperties)
    .setCache(CacheService.getScriptCache())
    .setScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly']);
}

var FIELDS_WHITELIST = [
  'country_name',
  'country_code',
  'indicator_name',
  'year',
  'value'
];
var BASE_SQL =
  'SELECT {{FIELDS}} FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_health_population.health_nutrition_population`';

function makeSQL(request) {
  // Create an object of {[fieldName]: boolean} to use as a constant time lookup.
  var simpleSet = FIELDS_WHITELIST.reduce(function(obj, field) {
    obj[field] = true;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  var requestFieldNames = request.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  var fieldNames = FIELDS_WHITELIST.filter(function(fieldName) {
    return simpleSet[fieldName];
  });
  var fieldsSQL = fieldNames.join(', ');
  return BASE_SQL.replace('{{FIELDS}}', fieldsSQL);
}

function getData(request) {
  var accessToken = getOauthService().getAccessToken();
  var serviceAccountCreds = getServiceAccountCreds();
  var billingProjectId = serviceAccountCreds[BILLING_PROJECT_ID];
  var sql = makeSQL(request);

  return cc
    .newBigQueryConfig()
    .setAccessToken(accessToken)
    .setBillingProjectId(billingProjectId)
    .setUseStandardSql(true)
    .setQuery(sql)
    .build();
}
```

Whenever I run either `getOauthService()` or `getData()` I get 'Cannot read property 'private key string' from null

Any help or tutorial fit for a 5-year old is highly appreciated.

Comment: 1.Show your script hiding sensitive details, but maintaining it's format. 2.Link documentations you're referring to

Comment: As @TheMaster mentioned, it's helpful if you provide the documentation URL in order to get more context regarding your issue. Can you comment or edit your post for adding the documentation?

Comment: DataStudio Advanced Services: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/advanced-services

World Bank Example
https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/world-bank/src

@JoseVasquez TheMaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

In your `getServiceAccountCreds` function you are retrieving a field by using an object `scriptProperties.getProperty(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS)` which is **SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS**. As per the [Google Apps Script: Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getpropertykey) example, the only type of parameter expected is a *String*. For that reason, you should avoid parsing the JSON and use the Properties object created at the beginning of the code.

I recommend you to use the following code.

### Code

Replace your code

```
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS = '{'+
  '"type": "service_account",'+
  '"project_id": "string for the project id",'+
  '"private_key_id": "string for the private key id",'+
  '"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----the private key-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",'+
  '"client_email": "serviceaccount@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",'+
  '"client_id": "the client id",'+
  '"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",'+
  '"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",'+
  '"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",'+
  '"client_x509_cert_url": "url"'+
'}';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'private key string';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'serviceaccount@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
var BILLING_PROJECT_ID = 'projectid';

/**
 * Copy the entire credentials JSON file from creating a service account in GCP.
 */
function getServiceAccountCreds() {
  return JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS));
}
```

For this code

```
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS_PROPS = {
    type: "service_account",
    project_id: "string for the project id",
    private_key_id: "string for the private key id",
    private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----the private key-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    client_email: "serviceaccount@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    client_id: "the client id",
    auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    client_x509_cert_url: "url"
  };
scriptProperties.setProperties(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS_PROPS);

var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'private_key';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'client_email';
var BILLING_PROJECT_ID = 'project_id';

/**
 * Copy the entire credentials JSON file from creating a service account in GCP.
 */
function getServiceAccountCreds() {
  return scriptProperties.getProperties();
}
```

### Reference

[Google Apps Script: PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)

[Google Apps Script: Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, altough the connector code ran in apps script after @Jose Vasquez suggestion, per using it on Google Data Studio returned an error `Insufficient permissions to the underlying data set.`. Upon further evaluation of the tutorial, I missed a very important point. The json corresponding to the credentials should not be pasted in the code itself, but rather referenced in the project properties:

[image: In english: File > Project Properties]

And then on the Script Properties tab, as a key-value pair, the key being `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS` and the value being the content of the json service account key:

[image: In english the tab name is Script Properties]

Then, the code replacement becomes from:

```js
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS = '{'+
  '"type": "service_account",'+
  '"project_id": "string for the project id",'+
  '"private_key_id": "string for the private key id",'+
  '"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----the private key-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",'+
  '"client_email": "serviceaccount@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",'+
  '"client_id": "the client id",'+
  '"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",'+
  '"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",'+
  '"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",'+
  '"client_x509_cert_url": "url"'+
'}';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'private key string';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'serviceaccount@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
var BILLING_PROJECT_ID = 'string for the project id';

/**
 * Copy the entire credentials JSON file from creating a service account in GCP.
 */
function getServiceAccountCreds() {
  return JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS));
}
```

to simply:

```js
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS = 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'private_key';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'client_email';
var BILLING_PROJECT_ID = 'project_id';

/**
 * Copy the entire credentials JSON file from creating a service account in GCP.
 */
function getServiceAccountCreds() {
  return JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS));
}
```

Since the service account credentials are already set in the script properties